# CSS как установить позиционирование от нижнего угла

Tags: позиционирование, css

По умолчанию в css позиционирование ведется от верхнего левого угла, а мне нужно установить наоборот (от правого нижнего), что бы изображение бекграунда начиналось от низа, а уже вверху резалось, в зависимости от размера экрана. При всём этом, в блоке CSS содержится следующий код:

```
 .main section.page2 {
      background: url(../images/pg2_bg2.png), url(../images/pg2_bg1.png);
      repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
      position: fixed, absolute;
    }
```

Т.е. по сути, у меня два бекграунда и для каждой функции нужно задавать по два свойства. Пробовал через bottom: 0; - не выходит. Подскажите, как поступить :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.main section.page2 {
  background: url(../images/pg2_bg2.png), url(../images/pg2_bg1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Не пойму, вы в один блок прописываете сразу 2 бэкграунда?
Так делать нельзя. Вам, как минимум, нужно создать блок внутри блока, и для каждого прописать отдельный бэкграунд, примерно так:

```
<div class="main">
<section>
    <div class="page1">
        <div class="page2">Ваш текст</div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
.main section .page1 {
      background: url(../images/pg2_bg2.png) no-repeat top left fixed; // позиционируется фиксировано в левом верхнем углу
    }

.main section .page2 {
      background: url(../images/pg2_bg1.png) no-repeat bottom right; // позиционируется относительно правого нижнего угла
    }
```

Comment: в css3 можно задавать несколько background описывая их через запятую

Comment: Я с точки зрения кроссбраузерности.